# What does the Swift-Icon in the Xcode 10 opening menu?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

I see a new shiny Swift-Icon in the opening mode from Xcode 10 (See screenshots). Can someone clarify what function is behind that icon.

[image: Opening Menu with disabled Icon]

[image: Opening Menu with enabled Icon]

We suppose that only swift files would showed, but that is not the case. Tested with an mixed project.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't currently have access to Xcode 10, but I would guess that in the latter case opening the header files will show you the Swift generated interface for them (therefore counting as "Swift files").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamish's comment is correct. When the Swift icon is solid blue, it means Xcode will show you the compiler-generated Swift interface corresponding to the selected header file.